# SonarQube - Private fields only used as local variables in methods should become local variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am doing SonarQube scan run of ASP.NET MVC project. I am getting below issue for private field.

```
 private String _ZipCode = "";
```

issue -

> Remove the '_ZipCode' field and declare it as a local variable in the relevant methods.

but _ZipCode is used in public property -

```
 [Required]
    public String ZipCode
    {
        get
        {
            TblZipCode zipcode = (_ZipCodeID != 0) ? TblZipCode.Get<TblZipCode>(_ZipCodeID) : new TblZipCode();
            return zipcode.ZipCode;
        }
        set { _ZipCode = value; }
    }
```

I thought of doing this (assign blank value in set) -

```
 [Required]
    public String ZipCode
    {
        get
        {
            TblZipCode zipcode = (_ZipCodeID != 0) ? TblZipCode.Get<TblZipCode>(_ZipCodeID) : new TblZipCode();
            return zipcode.ZipCode;
        }
        set 
        { 
         _ZipCode = "";
         _ZipCode = value; 
        }
    }
```

Is my code logic valid? Can I assign default value to private field in public property(set method). Or what is other way?

Comment: Looking at your code it seems that the getter doesn't use the value of `_ZipCode` which is the value that is updated in the setter. If that is true it seems like a bug and might be why SonarCube flags it because `_ZipCode` is never read.

Comment: I agree @MartinLiversage. but now I used _ZipCode in get logic. SonarQube still generate that error. Is it because private variable should not be assigned?

Comment: I'm not a SonarCube user but ReSharper has a similar refactoring it suggest when you use a field as a local variable in a single method. You can replace the field with a local variable which definitely is an improvement. So either `_ZipCode` is only used within a single method (and _method_ also includes property setter and getter methods) or SonarCube is flagging a false positive. You can try to remove the field from the class and replace it with a local variable where it's used. If you do that in more than one method you should undo the change. Otherwise it should remove the warning.